# Emberjs: access triggering element in route (bootstrap popover as nested route)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm trying to use a bootstrap popover with a nested route in Ember.  Here the contents of the popover are the rendered contents of the nested route, and I want the popover to appear over the button that triggered it.  Right now I've got things set up such that the button triggers the transition to the nested route, then on the `didInsertElement` for the view in the nested route, I finally execute the code to show the popover on the triggering element.  But in order to do so, I'm manually stitching together the id of the trigger element and calling the popover on it manually.  Like so:

```
App.PopoverView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function () {

        var controller = this.controller;

        if(controller && controller.get('model')){

            var uniqueId = controller.get('model').get('uniqueId');
            var triggerBtn = $('#unique-trigger-' + uniqueId);

            triggerBtn.popover({
                html: true,
                title: 'Popover Title',
                placement: 'left',
                content: getPopoverContent,
                trigger: 'focus'
            });         

            triggerBtn.popover('show');

            triggerBtn.on('hidden.bs.popover', function(){
                controller.send('close');
            });

        }

        function getPopoverContent() {
            return $('.popover-content');
        }
    }
});
```

This seems to work, but it feels really icky in terms of clean, maintainable code, and separation of concerns.  And it surely can't be the "Ember way".  But I'm having a hard time sorting out for myself what's the best way to accomplish something like this.

Comment: You should use a component for you popover I think.

Comment: Thanks. Any thoughts on how I'd solve that identifying-the-triggering-element problem with a component?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a component for the bootstrap popover, you could implement it like this :

```
var BootstrapPopoverComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'div', // The default tagname
    classNames: 'btn btn-default', // Any class you want
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var component = this,
            contents = this.$('.popoverJS');
            component.$().popover({
                animation: false,
                placement: component.get('placement'),
                html: true,
                content: contents
            }).on('show.bs.popover', function() {
                contents.removeClass('hide');
            });
    },
    willDestroyElement: function() {
        this.$().popover('destroy');
    }
});
```

I assume you know how the `{{yield}}` is working.
Inside your component template :

```
{{btnText}}
<div class="popoverJS hide">
    {{yield}}
</div>
```

and here an example inside your template :

```
{{#bootstrap-popover btnText="ClickME" tagName="button"}}
// Whatever you want to render inside your popover
{{/bootstrap-popover}}
```

Like this, you have a reusable popover component in which you can display whatever you want, I don't know if it's the best implementation but it works well for me :)

Comment: That does look like an effective way of handling the popover in a component. But one of my requirements is that the contents of the popover would be a nested route. So the issue is that I really can't declare each popover target with a component because I can't have multiple outlets for the nested route. I basically have to have one outlet whose contents can be inserted in a popover on multiple page elements.

Comment: I'm using it to display nested route too. You can put `{{outlet}}` inside the bootstrap-popover bloc type, it's working fine.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Let me give it a try and get back to you.